# Formatting Date to get Day of Week

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to write in mediawiki syntax to show the day of the week?

I'd like to be able to enter in something like `#dateformat:2014-02-16|???` and get back `Sunday, February 16, 2014`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like this: `{{#time: l, F d, Y |2014-02-16}}`. Days of weeks are not always localized though, so you have to doublecheck that it works for all the languages you are using. Weekdays also won't work for dates before 1753.

Comment: ah, I had to enable the Parser Functions extension to get this to work.  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions#Installation

Comment: @DJStroky True, I forgot to mention that. And for really old MediaWiki versions you need to install it separately.